# Kibana: How to aggregate for all UUIDs

Tags: kibana

I am tracking my url hit counts and want to aggregate them.

I have a few URL as follows:
example.com/service/{uuid}

when I view in Kibana it lists out the total hit count of each URL individually so my table has something like:

```
example.com/homepage         100 count
example.com/service/uuid1     10 count
example.com/service/uuid2     5 count
```

Is there an easy way to combine all uuids into 1 entry?

I was thinking of replacing uuids with a static string, however the admins blocked regex support making the replacement very difficult. So I am trying to see if there is any other way before doing that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a new field with scripted fields.

The new field would return value: example.com/service/uuid if the url contains the word uuid. Otherwise it will return the url as it is.

Then you could do the aggregation on the new field.